# Not able to fetch the data from server with multiple rdp

Tags: powershell-remoting

We are running a batch file from Server1 which calls the Powershell scripts in Server2. The Powershell script will get the date and time of Server3.  When we trigger the execution from server1 it is not working. PowerShell script not able to get the server3 time. When we run the powershell script  manually from server2 it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with Double hopping. This is not allowed by default in PowerShell remoting.

To do it in that way , you will have to delegate your credential you use to run the script from server1 to server 2.

Do a `Get-Help Enable-WSMANCredSSP -Full`

You will get more info [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/08/02/windows-powershell-remoting-and-delegating-user-credentials/)

Regards,

Kvprasoon